# How do I add a new column in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, html, calendar, fullcalendar

I want to add a new column to the calendar, I don't know how to go about it. For example a column after the days column

Comment: You can't, it's not possible. Why would you need that anyway?

Comment: I want to add a summary column at the end of the days

Comment: What would the summary contain exactly? You could perhaps put it somewhere else in your UI. Adding it into fullCalendar is probably impossible, and certainly very difficult to it it neatly and to cope with changes of view